# How to hide all Nimble and Nim outputs including errors?

Tags: command-line, nim-lang

How can I hide all Nimble and Nil outputs including errors?

I used this command `nimble build --silent`, but it still throws errors when there are errors.

How can I disable that?

Comment: What kind of errors do you not want to show? Errors in your nim code?

Comment: I want to hide literally All of them.

Comment: Why would you want to hide errors in your code? You won't know why your code doesn't compile

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though, what you want to accomplish is to hide all output from `nim` and `nimble`.
While it's unclear why this would be desirable, you can hide all outputs quite easily. This isn't restricted to nim and nimble, but any program.
Though it does somewhat depend on where you are running the command.

On linux / sh, you can hide outputs by redirecting to `/dev/null`:

```sh
program &> /dev/null
```

On windows, in cmd or batch files, you would:

```
program > NUL 2> NUL
```

whereas on powershell you would:

```
program > $null 2> $null
```

What actually happens in that case is that stdout and stderr are being replaced. This makes it so that what is being written to these streams is never actually outputed. If you only wanted to temporarily hide them, but see/check the outputs later, you could also substitute `/dev/null` , `NUL` or `$null` with a file path, which is where the output would be written to as a file.